# H27 - Client Request Interrupted

Tags: ios, django, heroku, nsurlsession

I am getting [H27 warnings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/662) in heroku for a django based app, for requests possibly requiring long running processing. The strange thing is, the request doesn't fail but appears to be executed twice. I.e. if my request should create one object, I get two objects instead. Looking at the logs it looks like the request is starting again just after the warning is emitted. The first warning happens about 10 seconds after the start of the initial request.

Those request are post requests coming from an ios app.

Is this to be expected? Where should I be looking to debug this? (on top of that, I can't really reproduce, but it seems to happen from time to time).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have this exact scenario occurring - I'm hours into this with zero help from Google. (The fact I'm using Laravel + Browser should be irrelevant because this sounds like a Heroku dyno/routing symptom, perhaps as a result of long running web requests.)

Comment: Nope. I added random delays on the server side to mitigate the issue and didn't look at it recently.

Comment: Word. I ended up using a file lock so I'm fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally client shouldn't redo POST requests as they are not [idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).

Maybe the library you are using is redoing a POST request after the first one gets interrupted (for example 3g-wifi switch, or a default timeout of the library)

Do you own the clients? You could make a client-level log and check it. Maybe give a random parameter to each request and check if 2 requests have the same random parameter, if so the library is doing something wrong.

Comment: Good debug id, I'll add this random param check (will get me some time to get results, though).